# Thread issues with Itext PDF

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itextpdf

Threads are getting stuck waiting for lock while using Itext Pdf to merge pdfs in the application, can someone help on cause and fix?

java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

```
        "[STUCK] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" RUNNABLE

            com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ByteBuffer.append(ByteBuffer.java:225)

            com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ByteBuffer.append(ByteBuffer.java:236)

            com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfSmartCopy$ByteStore.serObject(PdfSmartCopy.java:165)

            com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfSmartCopy$ByteStore.serArray(PdfSmartCopy.java:185)

            com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfSmartCopy$ByteStore.serObject(PdfSmartCopy.java:156)

            com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfSmartCopy$ByteStore.serDic(PdfSmartCopy.java:176)

            com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfSmartCopy$ByteStore.serObject(PdfSmartCopy.java:153)
```

.......

com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfSmartCopy$ByteStore.serDic(PdfSmartCopy.java:176)

```
            com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfSmartCopy$ByteStore.serObject(PdfSmartCopy.java:146)

            com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfSmartCopy$ByteStore.<init>(PdfSmartCopy.java:198)

            com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfSmartCopy.copyIndirect(PdfSmartCopy.java:93)
```

Comment: Which version of iText are you using? Didn't we fix the `PdfSmartCopy` a couple of releases ago? Current release is 5.5.6.

Comment: The OP might also present some code.

Comment: Hi Bruno, do you have any documentation that I can refer on this issue?

Comment: Actually I was using 5.1.3 version, can you please tell me which version\release you fixed it

Comment: It's probably somewhere hidden in the [changelogs](http://itextpdf.com/changelog), but I don't have the time to look for it. In any case: 5.1.3 dates from November 2011. That's quite old. You should upgrade.